# NASM - is this the address, value?

Tags: syntax, nasm, dereference

#### TL;DR

Is `[memloc]` referring to the value or the address?  If it's referring to either, then why does it work both as a value *and* an address?  *(see code below, lines 4 and 5)*

### Full question...

Sorry for the long question.
I'm confused by label dereferencing in NASM. Take this example:

```
01| section .text
02| ; exiting the program with exit code "15"
03|
04| mov     [memloc], 15 ; move 15 into memloc
05| push    [memloc]     ; push memloc on stack
06| mov     eax, 1       ; prepare exit syscall
07| call    kernel       ; invoke syscall
08|
09| section .data
10| memloc: dd 0    ; let's say this is at address 0x1234
```

When I run it, it exits with code 15.  It works!
*...but why?*  Shouldn't `memlock` be without braces line 4, where `push` presumably expects a destination?

For example:
The `mov` instruction at line `04` moves the value 15 to the ADDRESS of memloc:

```
mov     [memloc], 15 ; move 15 into mem @memloc
```

But line `05` pushes the VALUE stored at memloc onto the stack:

```
push    [memloc]     ; push value @memloc on stack
```

So, is `[memloc]` the value (`15`) or the address (`0x1234`)?  What happens in theory if you `mov memloc, 15` instead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the operation treats its operands differently based on whether you put braces around it, then I guess my question is 'how does the machine code differentiate between addresses and values?'

Comment: It doesn't, which is the reason you have to put braces around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than 1 version of the `mov` instruction. If the compiler (NASM) sees the square brackets around *memloc* it generates one form of `mov` and if your compiler doesn't see the square brackets around *memloc* it generates another form of `mov`.

Consider the following instructions:

```
mov edx, memloc
mov edx, [memloc]
mov [memloc], edx
```

They're all `mov` to/from the same destination/source register EDX but the compiler (NASM) will generate completely different opcodes for these instructions.

The 1st `mov` is encoded with 5 bytes 0xBA, ?, ?, ?, ?
The 2nd `mov` is encoded with 6 bytes 0x8B, 0x15, ?, ?, ?, ?
The 3rd `mov` is encoded with 6 bytes 0x89, 0x15, ?, ?, ?, ?

The 4 **?**'s represent the address of *memloc* as assigned by NASM.
Using the example address (0x1234) in your question this would become:

The 1st `mov` is encoded with 5 bytes 0xBA, 0x34, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00
The 2nd `mov` is encoded with 6 bytes 0x8B, 0x15, 0x34, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00
The 3rd `mov` is encoded with 6 bytes 0x89, 0x15, 0x34, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00

Comment: This is definitely what was causing my confusion.  I was thinking that the brackets denote a change in the reference, when they really change the operation.  Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

> What happens in theory if you `mov memloc, 15` instead?

NASM would not except this because you can't move an immediate value (15) into another immendiate value (*memloc*).

> The mov instruction at line 04 moves the value 15 to the ADDRESS of memloc:

The instruction at line 4 does not change the address of *memloc*.
Just like line 5 it uses the value stored at *memloc*.

> So, is [memloc] the value (15) or the address (0x1234)?

`[memloc]` is the value 15
`memloc` is the address 0x1234 (which you can't change after it has been set by the line 10 of your code)

Comment: Okay, but the `mov` instruction must know the _address_ of where it's putting the information. Just like if I told you to put mail in a mailbox, you'd need to know the mailing address. I couldn't give you the mail that was in the box and expect you to magically find it, right? (assume none of the mail has the address on it, lol)

Comment: @JamesM.Lay There's more than 1 version of the `mov` instruction. If the compiler (NASM) sees the square brackets around *memloc* it generates one form of `mov` and if your compiler doesn't see the square brackets around *memloc* it generates another form of `mov`.

Comment: @user3144770 So, when you `mov [mem], eax`, the address is still passed, but to an opcode that expects an offset? So instead of viewing `mem` as a "find and replace" target, I should think of it more like a C pointer, where `mov [mem],eax` is like `*mem = eax` and `push [mem]` is like `push(*mem)`?

Comment: (...if there were an analogous function to push in c that gave you programmatic access to the stack.)

Comment: @user3144770 if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.