# NASM - Storing the address of one variable in another variable

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-address

I'm currently learning Assembly.
I want to write a program which ends up with three variables that point to each other:

```
0x804a000: 0x804a001  ; 0 -> 1
0x804a001: 0x804a002  ; 1 -> 2
0x804a002: 0x804a000  ; 2 -> 0
```

[According](https://ncona.com/2019/02/assembly-variables-instructions-and-addressing-modes/) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608423/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-x86-assembly) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412100/nasm-is-this-the-address-value) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567621/how-do-i-print-an-address-in-x86-nasm-assembly-language) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534374/7242251), I can retrieve (e. g. for `mov`):

- the contents of a variable `x` using `[x]`
- the address of a variable `x` using `x`

Here is what I came up so far:

```
section .bss
    head resd 3         ; reserve three dwords

section .text
  global _start
    
_start:

  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor ecx, ecx          ; counter = 0

  mov eax, head         ; move the address of head into eax: eax -> 0
  mov ebx, eax          ; move the address of head from eax into ebx: ebx -> 0
  add ebx, 2            ; ebx -> 2
  mov [ebx], eax        ; move the value of eax ( = the address of 0 ) into the address in ebx ( = the address of 2)
  
  loop:                 ; first run     second run
    inc ecx             ; eax -> 0      eax -> 1
    mov ebx, eax        ; ebx -> 0      ebx -> 1
    add eax, 1          ; eax -> 1      eax -> 2
    mov [ebx], eax      ; 0 -> 1            1 -> 2
    cmp ecx, 2          ; ecx = 1 < 2   ecx = 2 == 2
  jl loop

  mov eax, head         ; eax points to the first element
    
  mov   eax,1           ; system call number (sys_exit)
  int   0x80            ; call kernel
```

This should basically
0. reserve three dwords, the first of which is at the address in `head`

1. load the address of 0 into `eax`, the address of 2 into `ebx`
2. `mov [ebx], eax` write the address of 0 into 2 (`2 -> 0`)
3. Repeat the same for fields 0 and 1: `0 -> 1`, `1 -> 2`
4. Store the address of head into eax

Now I assemble and run the whole thing using

```
nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf test.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o test.out test.o
```

However, both the values in `0` and `2` are wrong, as I can check using `gdb`:

```
gdb test.out
(gdb) b 27 // break after mov eax, head
(gdb) r
(gdb) i r eax
eax     0x804a000    134520832 // eax points to head
(gdb) print *134520832
$1 = 77595137                  // cell 0 does not point to cell 1
(gdb) print *134520833
$2 = 134520834                 // cell 1 does point to cell 2
(gdb) print *134520834
$3 = 134743200                 // cell 2 does not point to cell 1
```

Where do these wrong values come from?

Maybe this happens because I try to write the entire 32bit `eax` into the 16bit dword?
I tried changing the lines to `mov [ebx], ax` but ended up with the same result.

Another reason I could come up with was that the memory addresses are bigger than a `dword`, so I tried to use `qword`s instead but ended up with another wrong result.

I also tried using the `lea` instruction as sugested in [lea assembly instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153282/lea-assembly-instruction), which lead to the same result.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A dword is 32-bit in x86, so 4 bytes.  "double word", where a "word" is 16-bit (because x86 evolved out of 16-bit 8086).  And yes as you discovered, x86 is byte-addressable, like all modern mainstream ISAs.

Also, the answer to your title question would be `mov dword [head], head+4` for example.  `head+4` is evaluated at assemble+link time and turns into a 32-bit immediate operand holding that address, while `head` turns into a 32-bit displacement holding the other address.

Or you could use a loop like you're doing, but simplify with `mov [eax-4], eax` to store the address of the current element into the previous element, with `add eax,4` to advance the pointer.  No need for copying to EBX, just use an addressing mode for the memory operand for constant offsets.

Write it in C and look at compiler output if you want full examples of whole loops / functions. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading some more about this, the solution is pretty obvious.
Each address corresponds to a single byte. If all my cells are qwords, I need to increase the address in each loop run by 4, not 1:

```
section .bss
    head resq 4         ; three qwords

section .text
  global _start
    
_start:

    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx        ; counter = 0

    mov eax, head       ; move the address of head into eax: eax -> 0
    mov ebx, eax        ; eax -> 0
    add ebx, 12         ; ebx -> 3
    mov [ebx], eax      ; 3 -> 0

    loop:               ; first run     second run
    inc ecx             ; counter = 0 counter = 1
    mov ebx, eax        ; ebx -> 0      ebx -> 1
    add eax, 4          ; eax -> 1      eax -> 2
    mov [ebx], eax      ; 0 -> 1            1 -> 2
    cmp ecx, 3          ; ecx = 1 < 2   ecx = 2 == 2
    jl loop

    mov eax, head       ; eax points to the first element
    
  mov   eax,1           ; system call number (sys_exit)
  int   0x80            ; call kernel
```

Addresses are (at least for my setup) up to 32 bits = 4 bytes large, so my first attempt wasn't working because I overwrote each address with the next address written. That's why only the second value was correct - it was the last one that was written.

Comment: What ever happened to "I want to write a program which ends up with **three** variables that point to each other" This answer now deals with 4 variables! And why do you reserve 4 **Q**words instead of 3 **D**words?